# incorrect jackson date format from a rest service

Tags: android, json, date, jackson

I have a simple object with 2 dates like this

Example :

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int person_id;
    private Date person_date_time1;
    private Date person_date_time2;

//getter , setters

}
```

The json returned by the android rest service is structured like this

```
{
            "person_id": 11077,
            "person_date_time1": "2012-11-27", 
            "person_date_time2": "2011-11-27T08:30:00Z" 
}
```

The problem is the the dates parsed by the jackson formatter are incorrect :(

person.person_date_time1  prints Mon Nov 26 19:00:00 EST 2012 (one day less)
person.person_date_time2  prints Sun Nov 27 03:30:00 EST 2011 (5 hours less)

How can i define the correct format for deserializing dates with jackson on Android ?

The rest service android

```
@Rest(rootUrl = ConstantsUtils.URL, converters = { MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class })
@Accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface PersonRest extends RestClientErrorHandling {

    @Get("/person/{id}")
    Person getPerson(String id);
}
```

I can't use jodadatetime because i am using a api for persisting datas(realm.io) which works only with Date

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The Jakcson parser is fine, but it looks like you have a problem with how the date is represented on the JSON. The Jackson parser will follow an exact pattern for creating the Date object so you have to match it.

Comment: Thank you . I can't manipulate the datas present in the json. I need to add a format to the jackson deserializer . In spring we can with ObjectMapper , something like this getObjectMapper().getDeserializationConfig().setDateFormat(dateFormat); But i don't know how to do the same with jackson for Android + android annotations :(